# backtground image, 3 transparent png buttons, three links, and responsive. possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Alright...I can't think of a way to do this. Nothing seems to be working.I have a 770x250 image. And three 174x34 transparent button image png's. The 770x250 image should have three clickable link areas: the first third, middle third, and last third.

My strategy was to set the big image as the background of a div. And then float:left the three png's on top of it with appropriate margin to place it correctly over the background image. And then make the widths of each element containing the images as 33%.

Something like this:

```
<div class="topimage">
  <ul>
    <li><img style="float:left;" src="buttons3.png" /></li>
    <li><img style="float:left;" src="buttons3.png" /></li>
    <li><img style="float:left;" src="buttons3.png" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topimage{
   background: url(background) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;"
}

li{
  width: 33%;
  float:left;
  list-style: none;
}

ul{
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

However, you'll notice that the top div has no height...so you can't see the background. How can I scale the height of the background to be proportional with the width?

And how can I make this responsive? So that the whole shabang just scales with width?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7rFV3/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make it in a container :

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/7rFV3/2/

**HTML** :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="topimage">
        <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/174/34" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/174/34" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/174/34" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    other div
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    display:flex;
}
.topimage{
       background: url(http://placekitten.com/770/250) no-repeat center center;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    float:left;
}
```

**PS** :

You can add 
    `width:100%;` to the `.topimage` to make it full width.